# moving vb6 to ATL

Tags: atl, istream

I am trying to replace my old control(ActiveX control) which was build in VB6 to control build in ATL.(Microsoft Platforms). I have serialized the control(VB6) object using stream.This object has some properties which are configured by users. Now while deserializing the object i am able to load the new control(ATL) because both control have same Prog id and class id.But not getting correct property values.

need help...

Answer (score 0):

You are unlikely (well, that would be a surprise) to have binary compatibility for VB6 controls and C++ ATL controls, and having the same ProgID and `CLSID` is insufficient. What you could possibly do to pass persistent state between the two is `IPersistPropertyBag` interface and property bag to carry the property values.